# simple if else statement in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have been having issues with the way I want to write my if else logics in the new action of my controller. For instance a user has two different fildes in the user table, let us say premium_user and gold_user. How will I write an if else statement that says if a user is a premium user he can upload 3 books and if the user is a gold user he can upload unlimited books and of he is just a user without gold or premium he can only upload 2 books in the new action of my controller. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logic belongs into your model. You would probably set up an [STI Table](http://juixe.com/techknow/index.php/2006/06/03/rails-single-table-inheritance/) which defines your user (silver, gold, usual folks,...) and manage authorisations with e.g [CanCan](http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan).

From there, you just need to update your view based on the type of your user.

Comment: You have a point with the sti table and I never knew abt it until today Thanks. But I actuall do know how to use it so much and the example given below is not compherensive enough to suit my case.

Comment: The fields I have  are just boolean fields.

Comment: I just wrote my logics with cancan and updated the views like u said and it works out just fine.

Comment: Using STI only to handle different values of a property seems a bit overkill to me.

Comment: @ChristophPetschnig it's a bit of a "cleanup" thing of me.

Answer (score 1):

well, you can choose to upload your books with a user form (using nested attributes), or directly with book form. you can put validation to the user.

```
class User
  has_many :books
  validates :books, :length => { if: Proc.new { |r| r.gold? }, allow_nil: true, maximum: 3, too_long: 'gold users can only upload 3 books' }    
  validates :books, :length => { if: Proc.new { |r| r.standard? }, allow_nil: true, maximum: 3, too_long: 'gold users can only upload 3 books' }
end


class Book
  belongs_to :user
  validates :user, :presence => true, associated: true
end
```

Even if you submit it via books, make sure you create a new books with `user.books.build`, in order for the validation to behave correctly.

Note that your controller new or create action will be the same, no need to fork on user type for validation.

Maybe you want to put a note in your books/new view or disable the form if users reach maximum allowable upload.

hope this helps